# mySQL auto increment increasing by 10 (ClearDB & Node)

Tags: mysql, node.js, cleardb

I have a simple table in ClearDB:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (

`id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`message` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm using Node to insert data into the table via:

```
var post = {username: response.user.name, message: message.text};

           connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", post, function(err, rows, fields) {

                 if (err) {
                       console.log('error: ', err);
                       throw err;
                 }

           });
```

However whenever I insert my id field increases by 10 rather than 1 (and it started off with 12:

id username message

12 test     test

22 test     test

32 test     test

42 test     test

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

It is ClearDB's strategy. [Here is the explanation from ClearDB's website.](http://w2.cleardb.net/index.php/faqs/#general_16)

You can't change this auto_increment step when you are using ClearDB.

---

This is the explanation from the link above.

> ClearDB uses circular replication to provide master-master MySQL
>   support. As such, certain things such as auto_increment keys (or
>   sequences) must be configured in order for one master not to use the
>   same key as the other, in all cases. We do this by configuring MySQL
>   to skip certain keys, and by enforcing MySQL to use a specific offset
>   for each key used. The reason why we use a value of 10 instead of 2 is
>   for future development.

Comment: This looks like a good answer to the question (thanks!), but could you [edit] and include the relevant information from the website in your answer? That way all information is preserved here, in case the link or content there changes.

Comment: @whrrgarbl Thanks, I did. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After some digging I found that I can change the `auto_increment`

Check first what value it is

```
SELECT @@auto_increment_increment
```

Then change it

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because of AUTO_INCREMENT field 
remove `AUTO_INCREMENT=11`