# laravel migration increment column problem

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7

After Deploy my laravel project to cloud (heroku) i noticed that when i trying to add new user or new role or new something .. the column id increment +10 ..
for example the first user id = 1 , the second user id = 11

for example this is my roles table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

[this is my roles table from mysql workbenck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGnKb.png)

Comment: Your question states that user id is the problem, but you posted migration for roles table

Comment: user is just an example for me the problem is come from all tables users roles profiles ....... etc

Comment: welcome to heroku, where everything you have ever done is now different

Answer (score 1):

it is related to `auto_increment_increment` settings of mysql.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Your `auto_increment_increment` is probably set to 10. you may set to 1 again via executing;

> `SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;`

Please check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)

Edit:

Since Heroku uses `cleardb`; it is not possible to change it while using cleardb. Here is the answer with the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38723706/2188922)

Comment: i try this but it still the same problem :/

Comment: after setting, when you execute `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` if it is printing `1 and 1` - then you may refresh your migrations and seeds ? @ilyésTabessi

Comment: is printing 10 and 1 . the default value of auto_increment_increment in mysql = 10 but when i run                      
       SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;                                                                                     the result is "0 row(s) affected"

Comment: It is not updating then it is not reflecting but it is okay it to print 0 rows affected, i checked on my local env - https://prnt.sc/sidfwr - could you double check whether you are running the command it correctly @ilyésTabessi

Comment: could you share the similar screenshot to what i shared - setting and getting the value @ilyésTabessi

Comment: Sir , i'm runing the commande correctly the 'auto_increment_increment' changed to 1 link 1 : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/20/7/1589719473-v1.png                                      but after some minutes i run the same commande but the 'auto_increment_increment' returned to 10                                                                                           link2: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/20/7/1589719491-v2.png                                     i think it is because some privileges of access or something like that .

Comment: i understand - probably some code, config or command is setting it back to 10 but i don't know who sets it back to 10, it may be related to your server, your code etc. Maybe you may search your project if there is any package, command, config has something ? @ilyésTabessi

Comment: @ilyésTabessi i searched some and found similar problem to yours; heroku is using cleardb as database - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38723706/2188922 please check here. i will update the answer too

Comment: yes i think the same , but in localhost it working fine i think the problem from the serve . any case big thanks for help sir :)

Comment: https://w2.cleardb.net/faqs/#general_16 here is the explanation - i updated the answer @ilyésTabessi - if it is okay for oyu, you may approve to help someone facing with the similar problem in the future. Have a good day

Comment: yes sir i see that , i will  approuve inshallah . thanks :)